# centering a border within a class

Tags: html, css

this is probably a laughable question but for some reason i just can't seem to align these guys so that they are totally centered.  For some reason the border box seems to be to the left and not sure why.  Can someone help...

jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/b3k9Lhfz/4/

the html and css

```
<div class="container-bottom">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="linkbutton">LEARN MORE</a>
            <h4><span></span>Click to find out more </h4>
            </div>


body {
    background: #fff;
}

.container-bottom h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size : 16px ;
  text-align:center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right : auto;
}

.linkbutton{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px; 
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.container-bottom{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 300px;
    height:20%;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
   margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  margin-top:30px;

  }
```

Comment: Just add `text-align: center;` to `.container-bottom`, it will also center the link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3k9Lhfz/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is inline so `margin: auto;` isn't going to work.

Use `text-align: center;` on the parent element instead.

```
.container-bottom {
    . . . 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is:

```
.linkbutton{
    /* You were missing this */
    display: block;
    /* Need this to align your text in the middle */
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    /* Controlling your padding here */
    padding: 10px;
    /* Specifying the width is important */
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```